# Bluetooth permissions in service

Tags: java, android

I'm porting an application plugin written Java that runs on Android.  It previously worked on Android SDK < 12, now (SDK > 12) it crashes when trying to connect to a bluetooth device.

The architecture is a little different than a typical Android app (as I understand it - I'm not an Android programmer). The part that I am porting inherits from ViewGroup and is loaded by the application as a plugin.  I don't declare or load an Activity.  The plugin manifest declares permissions and the bluetooth service and some plugin related values required by the application.

Part of the plugin is a service to handle bluetooth communications.  The service communicates with the plugin code via an IBinder retrieved by mMessenger.getBinder() where mMessenger is declared static in the Bluetooth service class that inherits from Service.

I can scan for bluetooth devices, but when I try to connect, the plugin closes/crashes.

I know that prior to SDK 12, runtime permissions were not required, but now with SDK > 12, I need to get runtime permissions:

```
String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
                        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
                        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN};
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissions, 2);
```

This is commented out because I don't have access to an activity in the plugin code or the service.  I've looked at the ViewGroup and didn't see any reference to an Activity.  The plugin class is initialized with a Context, but no activity.  Is there some way to get a temporary reference to an activity?

Another confusing aspect of this is that I call checkPermissions:

```
int permConnect = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(pluginContext, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT);
Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth connect permission = " + (permConnect == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ? "Granted" : "Denied"));
int permScan = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(pluginContext, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN);
Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth scan permission = " + (permScan == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ? "Granted" : "Denied"));
int permAdmin = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(pluginContext, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN);
Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth admin permission = " + (permAdmin == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ? "Granted" : "Denied"));
```

This code produces the following log entries:

```
2023-06-19T14:54:48.450Z [PluginTemplateDropDownReceiver]: Bluetooth connect permission = Granted
2023-06-19T14:54:48.451Z [PluginTemplateDropDownReceiver]: Bluetooth scan permission = Granted
2023-06-19T14:54:48.452Z [PluginTemplateDropDownReceiver]: Bluetooth admin permission = Granted
```

adb logcat -d includes the following line:

```
06-15 08:18:31.915 14057 14057 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.SecurityException: Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission for AttributionSource
```

So it looks to me like the plugin (not necessarily the service) thinks it has permissions and Android still kills it thinking it doesn't have permission for the connection.  Are permissions not application wide?  I was under the impression that the service would inherit permissions of the application.  Is this not the case?  If not, how do you get permissions in a service?

I'm sorry if this is a little cryptic, I am limited on what source code I can post.